# Big Query: SQL JOIN with column prefix

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables in Google Big Query. One table is kind of a product catalogue (1:1), while the second one is product related information (1:n). For a query I'm joining both. But the joins fails since the column `pid` and some others are present in both tables.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT tbl1.*, tbl2.* FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table_1`
  ) AS tbl1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table_2`) AS tbl2
ON tbl1.pid = tbl2.pid
WHERE tbl1.category LIKE '111002%'
```

**Idea 1:** How to select `*` without the duplicated columns (that I can put in manually).

**Idea 2:** How to provide a left/right prefix for the columns in the join?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid duplicating `pid` from both sides of the join, use a `USING` clause instead:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table_1`
  ) AS tbl1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table_2`) AS tbl2
USING(pid)
WHERE tbl1.category LIKE '111002%'
```

To prefix the column names from both sides of the join, use a reference to the tables in the select list instead of applying `.*` to them:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT tbl1, tbl2 FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table_1`
  ) AS tbl1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table_2`) AS tbl2
USING(pid)
WHERE tbl1.category LIKE '111002%'
```

The columns resulting from the query will be `tbl1` and `tbl2`, which are STRUCTs containing the columns from each of those tables as fields.

Comment: Thanks! The second statement worked, the first one didn't. Maybe because table 1 is actually a view? A further question: Should the WHERE be placed in the SELECT on the first table since that table is the smaller one? Or is Big Query optimizing the statement anyway?

Comment: BigQuery will "push down" the filter when it's outside the join (as long as you use standard SQL). I updated the first example, since I think it will work if you use `*` instead of `tbl1.*, tbl2.*`.